# Dell D6000 Docking station issues in Ubuntu

Tags: displaylink

I humbly seek assistance with my DEll D6000 docking station.

I am unable to install displaylink-drivers because it conflicts with evdi install. I'm unable to uninstall evdi because it appears to be not installed.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

I got the following info from AI:

*It seems like there was an error during the installation of the displaylink-driver package due to conflicts with the evdi package. To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:
Remove the problematic packages:
sudo dpkg -r evdi
sudo dpkg -r displaylink-driver
Update the package manager:
sudo apt update
Reinstall the displaylink-driver package:
sudo apt install displaylink-driver
By following these steps, you should be able to install the displaylink-driver package without any conflicts.*

======

I have tried the above and it didn't work. :

```
peter@pzx:~$ sudo dpkg -r evdi
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove evdi which isn't installed
peter@pzx:~$
```

======

Here is the output from trying to install the displaylink-driver:

```
peter@pzx:~$ sudo apt install displaylink-driver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
evdi
The following NEW packages will be installed:
displaylink-driver evdi
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/6,318 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 215936 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../evdi_1.14.1-7_amd64.deb ...
Error: Another EVDI distribution detected
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/evdi_1.14.1-7_amd64.deb (--unpack):
new evdi package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status
1
Preparing to unpack .../displaylink-driver_5.8.0-33_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/displaylink-driver_5.8.0-
33_amd64.deb (--unpack):
new displaylink-driver package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/evdi_1.14.1-7_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/displaylink-driver_5.8.0-33_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
peter@pzx:~$
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt purge evdi evdi-dkms` ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was resolved as follows:

```
sudo apt remove displaylink-driver 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install dkms libdrm-dev 
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.8.0-63.33.run 
reboot 
sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.8.0-63.33.run
```

Answer (score 1):

What we need to do is fix the "Error: Another EVDI distribution detected":

1. Figure out if there are any previous installs using: `dpkg -S /opt/displaylink` . If you get "no path found matching pattern", then skip to step 3
2. `sudo apt purge package_name` if any were found
3. `sudo rm -rf /opt/displaylink/`
4. Retry your installation

The cause of this is straightforward. Look at the "pre-installation script" (`preinst`) in `evdi_1.14.1-7_amd64.deb` and you will find the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -e /opt/displaylink/evdi.tar.gz ]]
then
  echo >&2 "Error: Another EVDI distribution detected"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: @peterzay Please post that as a separate answer so that it can be upvoted